# Google tagmanger not firing on sub-domain

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm setting up google analytics and a FB pixel with GTM for my sub-domain. I copied the tracking code the right way in the  and the  like I always do. When I use the preview mode of GTM on the root domain everything works up to the point you open the sub-domain. Then no GTM/GA/FBP is recognised.

The index.html page is set-up correctly and has been working for some time. In this document the code is visible in the chrome dev-tool but doesn't seem to do anything. In my cookie manager I'm able to find the relevant cookies though. Unfortunately the data isn't showing in GA or FB analytics.

Comment: Do you see the relevant tags firing in the GTM debug mode, on the subdomain?

Comment: @kgrg Thanks for the reply, the GTM debug mode does not open on the subdomain, also the Google Tag Assistant plug in for google chrome does not read the GTM code.

Comment: Sorry, but at this point it's hard to tell, what the problem could be. Could you please share the relevant codes of working and non-working implementations, masking any sensitive data, if necessary.

Comment: Did you fix this at the end?